# How to Convert "~/default.aspx" to "http://www.website.com/default.aspx" C#?

Tags: c#, methods

I know ASP.NET does this automatically, but for some reason I can't seem to find the method.

Help anyone?  Just as the title says.

If I do a Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx"), it works, but I don't want to redirect the site.  I just want the full URL.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the "/#{path}/Default.aspx" part, use:

```
Page.ResolveUrl("~/Default.aspx")
```

If you need more:

```
Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Host + ":" + Request.Url.Port
```

Answer (score 5):

In a web control, the method is `ResolveUrl("~/Default.aspx")`

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the [VirtualPathUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.virtualpathutility.aspx) class.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least three ways of doing this. I [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518199/control-resolveurl-versus-control-resolveclienturl-versus-virtualpathutility-toab) if there was any difference, but I didn't get any answer.

1. Control.ResolveUrl
2. Control.ResolveClientUrl
3. VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute

Comment: the difference between ResolveUrl and ResolveClientUrl is that ResolveClientUrl returns a path relative to the current page, ResolveUrl returns a path relative to the site root:
http://www.andornot.com/about/developerblog/2007/06/resolveurl-vs-resolveclienturl.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use:

```
Response.Redirect(Response.ApplyAppPathModifier("~/default.aspx"))
```

Comment: is there a difference between using the Response.ApplyAppPathModifier() and Page.ResolveUrl(), in particular when dealing with MVC pages (not web forms)?

Comment: oh, and I mean not for Redirect, but rather for getting URLs (e.g. setting src attributes, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article that explains the difference between the various ways to resolving paths in ASP.NET -

[Different approaches for resolving URLs in ASP.NET](http://refactoringaspnet.blogspot.com/2009/09/different-approaches-for-resolving-urls.html)