# Getting web address for local file in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

Is there a 'correct' way to get the proper web address for a file under an ASP.Net application?  For example, I have content in '/Content/Images/Gallery/2010-01-17/small/', and I would like to iterate through all of those files, and output to the browser a link.

Now, I can do it manually by working out the path from the files FullName or I can do it from knowing the current directory, but is there a proper ASP.Net way to do it?

As you can probably tell, I'd rather use the provided method if it exists :)

Regards

Moo

Comment: Are you looking for the reverse of Server.MapPath? I don't think you can. A URI is mapped to a single file, but a file on the disk can be mapped to multiple URIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method `ResolveUrl()` for that. If your content directory is located directly under you web app's root directory, then this should work:

```
// "~" results in an URL to your web app's root directory
string imageBaseUrl = this.ResolveUrl("~/content/gallery/2010-01-17/small");
```

Then you can append the names of the images to that base URL.

Answer (score 0):

I think ResolveUrl is only part of the answer.

Unfortunately, there is not a built-in function to return a full URL to a particular resource, inclusive of hostname and protocol.  Part of the reason for this is that you can access a URL any number of ways... and the server is completely agnostic of the hostname.  You have to look at either the Request.Url properties to build a new URL from the user's request, or use ServerVariables.

See this question:
[How to Convert "~/default.aspx" to "http://www.website.com/default.aspx" C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777944/how-to-convert-default-aspx-to-http-www-website-com-default-aspx-c)