# How to resolve a javascript path for pages that have different directory levels?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a javacript file (script.js, for example) in the following location:

/Website/Shared/Js/script.js

I have two pages which use this javascript, but each one of them seems to require a different path and I can't figure out how to resolve both of them.

One of them is the page:

/Website/One/Two/Three/page.aspx and this requires the path:

```
<script src="../../../Shared/Js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The other page is:

/Website/One/Two/page.aspx and this requires the path:

```
<script src="../../Shared/Js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I tried to come from the root by doing

```
<script src="../Shared/Js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="/Shared/Js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but none of these seem to work.  The temp solution I have found is to declare the script twice which is dumb, but that is all I can think of now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried ResolveClientUrl() ?

```
<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Shared/Js/script.js") %>
```

here is a good post on the differences.

[Control.ResolveUrl versus Control.ResolveClientUrl versus VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518199/control-resolveurl-versus-control-resolveclienturl-versus-virtualpathutility-toab)

Comment: Or is this directly in the script tag like this: <script src="<%= ResolveClientUrl("../Shared/Js/script.js") %> " type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Yes, like above. I updated my answer to link to a SO post on the differences. The west wind article is good as well.

Comment: Ok, it worked.  I had to make a slight change though, not sure if It had something to do with using Telerik controls, but this is what happened.  If I just put <script src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/Shared/Js/jquery.maskedinput-1.2.2.min.js") %>' type="text/javascript"></script>, I got the error message The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).  So I wrapped in a Telerik:RadScriptBlock and it worked.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use `~` before so server can resolve it for you.

```
<script src="~/Shared/Js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Another option is to use [base](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_base.asp) tag but that will effect other resources too.

Answer (score 0):

I do find using the : in front to work quite well. Example

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="<%: ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/lib/JQuery 1.7.2/jquery.min.js") %>">
   </script>
```