# Deployment to a shared web server causes my relative links to break

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm new to MVC3 and have the feeling this may be an obvious problem but nevertheless I can't find a related question on the issue.

I'm developing a web site in MVC3. My production environment has several web sites positioned as follows, eg:

www.companywebsite.com/app1/
www.companywebsite.com/app2/
...to
www.companywebsite.com/mynewapp/

I'm using IIS on Windows server2008 and have created the "mynewapp" folder. But when I deploy my application into this folder all my relative links and files break.

I've converted my scripts and images to T4-MVC references which seems to handle the relative paths but any bog-standard hyperlinks that I have as relative links will not work (and I don't want to convert them to Razor links due to use of images).

All my mapped routes are working fine without change.

Is there a global setting I can use for deployment to the production environment which will tell my project that the base folder is /mynewapp ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's a bog standard link?  Are you referring to standard references like and img reference, or script reference?

Comment: Sorry, I mean a page hyperlink such as <a href="/help">Help</a>

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574237/using-site-root-relative-links-in-razor) could help, but there's no easy answer..

Comment: Update: I've found a post which uses:<a href="@Url.Content("~/Help")">Help</a> which works for me where <a href="~/Help">Help</a> does not. Not sure why but it works.

Comment: It works because by using @Url.Content you're having the server generate the url's for you instead of asking the browser to do it. Since the server knows where it is, everything is happy!