# Ajax call not working on server

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have following code in my Javascript file:

```
$.getJSON("/ProductMatrix/LocationList/" + $("#categoryTypeFilter > option:selected").attr("value"),
  function (data) {
    var items = "<option> Default  </option>";
    $.each(data,
      function (i, location) {
        items += "<option value=' " + location.Value + "'>" + location.Text + "</option>";
      });
    $("#captureLocationFilter").html(items);
  });
```

`"/ProductMatrix/LocationList/"` is controller/action but its not working on server, however it does work on Local machine. Looks like there is problem with url, as this path may not be existing on server. Can someone help me on it.

When I try Url.Action my external javascript file is not happy.

[image]

Comment: Please carefully read the answer. `Url.Action` is a server method. It won't work in external js files. you need to build the url in your razor file and pass it to your js code as clearly explained in this post [How do I make JS know about the application root?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34360537/how-do-i-make-js-know-about-the-application-root)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My wild guess is that you are getting a 404 error. Check your browser console.

One suggestion is, do not hard code the url to your action method like that. Always try to use the html helper methods like `Url.Action` or `Url.RouteUrl` to build the correct relative url to your action method.

```
var url="@Url.Action("LocationList","ProductMatrix")";
var v=$("#categoryTypeFilter > option:selected").attr("value");
//update the url (add ? as needed) according to how your server expects the url params
$.getJSON(url + v , function (data) {              
             //do something with data    
});
```

This will work fine if your javascript code is inside a razor view, If it is inside an external javascript file, use the solution explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34360537/how-do-i-make-js-know-about-the-application-root).

Comment: I tried that but looks like in my external javascript file is not liking it .Please find screen shot attached in question description.

Comment: Read the answer carefully. For external js file you should try the other approach i mentioned in the link

Comment: Isn't it possible without angular?

Comment: It is. Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34427447/angularjs-directive-templateurl-doesnt-work-while-template-works/34427511#34427511