# What's the correct way to pass in tilde path in javascript in order to get the relative path?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a tilde path. I would like to convert it into client url

```
    var path = "~/Presentation/Resources/Images/masterPage/cleanup.png";
    var a =  '<%=Page.ResolveClientUrl(" '+path+' ") %>';

    var b = '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Presentation/Resources/Images/masterPage/cleanup.png") %>';

alert("var a-->"+a);
alert("var b-->"+b);
```

although the code above seems the same, the results I obtain for var a and var b are very different.

**Result**

```
var a --> ~/Presentation/Resources/Images/masterPage/cleanup.png
var b --> ../../Resources/Images/masterPage/cleanup.png
```

I have a variable that stores the path, but I failed to get the result exactly like var b.
What can I do for **var a** so that I can get the result like **var b**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods you are calling, ResolveClientUrl and ResolveUrl, are different. ResolveClientUrl tells you the URL relative to the page you are on; ResolveUrl tells you the URL relative to the site root. You can find a more thorough description at http://www.andornot.com/blog/post/ResolveUrl-vs-ResolveClientUrl.aspx

There is also more info in this other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518199/control-resolveurl-versus-control-resolveclienturl-versus-virtualpathutility-toab).

Comment: well,i tried with ResolveUrl and ResolveClientUrl. both of this also not returning me the "../../" relative path  :(